# How to Setup an RSS Feed using Feedburner?

Tags: web, rss, feedburner

I've searched Google, but only found information on how to setup a feedburner for wordpress or other blogging services. I've also searched stackoverflow, but not found the right information.

I'm creating a website, for which I want to have an RSS. Feedburner seems to be a good, free option - so I'd like to use that.

When I go to feedburner, using my google account, it says the website I want to claim is invalid. And it's not clear how to make it valid. I also have no experience with RSS (and really websites in general), so I'm not sure where to go from here.

What are the steps I need to take, starting from scratch, to add an RSS feed (with feedburner) to a website?

Answer (score 0):

Feedburner knows how to integrate with WordPress and several others. However if your site is built using different technologies (PHP, ASP.NET), FeedBurner has no idea on how to get updates. On my websites, I create my own RSS feeds (with PHP), and then burn them using FeedBurner so I get all the extras it offers.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I have my own RSS feed, but I can not get FeedBurner to recognize it. Any advise?

Comment: I advise you to open a question for this, adding some additional details.